# How to find the multiple instances of a data between two special characters in python

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python so please excuse me if my question is two simple. I want to find the multiple instances of data between two special characters in a string and also count the number of instances. Until now I have the following code.

```
import re
count=0
myString="abcde(fghi)defggdfsidf(ijkl)gfders(gkjh)hgstfvd"
startString = '('
endString = ')'
for item in myString:
 portString=myString[myString.find(startString)+len(startString):myString.find(endString)]
 print(portString)
 count=count+1
```

My desired output is

```
fghi
ijkl
gkjh
```

But my code always start the loop from the start and produces fghi. Can any one tell me what is the problem?

Comment: Use spaces in your code and try to spread long lines over multiple lines to make your code more readable. And use 4 space tabs instead of 1 space tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use non greedy regexes:

```
count=0
myString="abcde(fghi)defggdfsidf(ijkl)gfders(gkjh)hgstfvd"
rx = re.compile(r'\((.*?)\)')   # non greedy version inside parens
pos = 0
while True:
    m = rx.search(myString[pos:])   # search starting at pos (initially 0)
    if m is None: break
    count += 1
    print(m.group(1))
    pos += m.end()                  # next search will start past last ')'
```

---

Above solution only makes sense if parentheses are correctly balanced or if you want to start on first opening one and end of first closing next.

If you want to select text parenthesed text containing no opening or closing parentheses, you have to specify it in the regex:

```
myString="abcde(fghi)defg(gdfsidf(ijkl)g(fders(gkjh)hgstfvd"
rx = re.compile(r'\(([^()]*)\)')
pos = 0
while True:
    m = rx.search(myString[pos:])   # search starting at pos (initially 0)
    if m is None: break
    count += 1
    print(m.group(1))
    pos += m.end()                  # next search will start past last ')'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I needed a non greedy version and hence your solution works in some situation. However if the input string slightly differs like myString="abcde(fghi)defg(gdfsidf(ijkl)g(fders(gkjh)hgstfvd" in such case the output is changed which I do not want. Can you also suggest some change to cater for such a situation. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to regex if you'd prefer to keep the loop, note that `String.find()` can take an optional parameter to tell it where to start looking. Just keep track of the where the closing parenthesis is and start again from just after that.

Unfortunately it's not quite so simple as the loop condition will have to change too, so that it stops after hitting the last set of parentheses.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
count=0
myString="abcde(fghi)defggdfsidf(ijkl)gfders(gkjh)hgstfvd"
startString = '('
endString = ')'
endStringIndex = 0
while True:
    startStringIndex = myString.find(startString, endStringIndex+1)
    endStringIndex = myString.find(endString, endStringIndex+1)
    if (startStringIndex == -1):
      break
    portString=myString[startStringIndex+len(startString):endStringIndex]
    print(portString)
    count+=1
```

Output:

```
fghi
ijkl
gkjh
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
>>> myString = "abcde(fghi)defggdfsidf(ijkl)gfders(gkjh)hgstfvd"
>>> matches = re.findall(r'\((\w+)\)', myString)
>>> count = len(matches)
>>> print('\n'.join(matches))
fghi
ijkl
gkjh
>>> print(count)
3
```